# Convert @JmsListener code to String Integration DSL

Tags: jms, listener, spring-integration, spring-dsl

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myListener")
    public void receive(Event even) {

            if (event.myObj().isComp()) {
                service1.m1(even);
            }
            if (event.myObj2().isdone()) {
                service2.m2(event);
            }
    }
```

**I tried various combinations, and one of them is below**

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("incomingQueue"))
                .<Event>filter(e -> ((Event)e).myObj().isComp()).handle(service1, "m1")
                .<Event>filter(e -> ((Event)e).myObj2().isdone()).handle(service2, "m2")//looks like its not called
                .get();
    }
```

But it does not executes on 2nd filter/condition. Please suggest what I am missing here

Comment: sorry, it worked, after I put @ServiceActivator on m1 as well as m2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked, after I put @ServiceActivator annotation on m1 as well as m2. My bad, I missed this annotation while converting code to SI

Comment: Well, actually that isn't good. You specify an explicit method name for `handle()`, therefore exactly that method can be called, independently of the annotation. Please, share a StackTrace on the matter. Also how does your `service2.m2()` declaration look?